# dpkg-buildpackage: install to /usr/games instead of /usr bin

Tags: package-management

I'm building my first Debian package for a small game project, and it builds fine from the C sources, but the compiled executable gets installed in /usr/bin. How can I get it installed in /usr/games instead?

I've tried adding it to debian/install like so:

```
obj-x86_64-linux-gnu/mygame usr/games
```

but that only works when building a package for x86_64, because on other architectures, the build directory is obviously going have a different name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to learn by small example like https://packages.ubuntu.com/source/hirsute/xball .

This `xball` package has the following in `debian/rules`:

```
override_dh_auto_configure:
    dh_auto_configure -- \
        --prefix=/usr \
        --bindir=/usr/games \
        --datadir=/usr/share/games/xball
```

in the above `--bindir=/usr/games` will do what you want.

You can do the same for your code.

---

Update based on comment from OP. For `cmake` based build:

> I ended up looking at [`blockattack`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/source/hirsute/blockattack), which does this:
>
> ```
> override_dh_auto_configure: 
>   dh_auto_configure -- \
>       -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release \ -DINSTALL_BIN_DIR=/usr/games \
>       -DINSTALL_DATA_DIR=share/games/blockattack
> ```

Comment: This seemed good, but didn't work. Could it be because my project is built with cmake, not autotools?

Comment: I do not really know, all Ubuntu repository is available as examples for you. Try to find cmake-built package to use it as prototype.

Comment: For cmake, I ended up looking at blockattack, which does this:

    override_dh_auto_configure:
 dh_auto_configure -- \
  -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release \
  -DINSTALL_BIN_DIR=/usr/games \
  -DINSTALL_DATA_DIR=share/games/blockattack
Thanks for your help!